# I can't access request in my Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

**Hello Awesome People!**

A simple question. I have this view:

```
def hello(request):
     users_list = User.objects.all()
     context = {"users_list":users_list}
     return render_to_response('index/users-list.html',context=context)
```

In my template, I want to access COOKIES, with `request`

```
 {% for u in users_list %}
 {% if u.id in request.COOKIES.room|split %}
       remove user
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

I tried displaying `{{request.COOKIES}}`, nothing shown however the key exists. It seems that request isn't available in the template.

> split is a custom tag filter

```
@register.filter    
def split(string_,sep=","):
    return string_.split(sep)
```

**Why I can't access the request?**, and also none of my global variables available in my `project/context_processors.py` are accessible

Comment: Because you do not pass it to the `render_to_response(..)` call. Use `return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)` instead.

Comment: Based on what you said, I need to send the `request` via `render_to_response()` as well. what about all my global variables available in context_processors?

Comment: But the only difference between the two is that it first constructs a `RequestContext`, so the difference is functionally almost nothing else but adding a `request` for the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `render_to_response`, it's been obsolete since `render` was introduced in Django 1.3. The `render_to_response` function was deprecated in Django 2.0 and will finally [be removed in Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-3-0).

In this case, change the view to use `render` as follows:

```
 return render(request, 'index/users-list.html', context=context)
```

Assuming you have the `request` [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) enabled in `TEMPLATES` (it is enabled in the default generated settings file), you will then be able to access `request` in the template.

Comment: Thank you! Is this method will also available if I want to refresh a part of the DOM? for instance, I use `users_list` to display all the users in a modal, it is a separated view. When a user click on like `<a>show users list</a>`, I call this view to refresh only the modal. will `render()` do it ?

Comment: The `render` shortcut simply renders the template to html and returns that in an HTTP response. You can use it for regular requests and AJAX requests. However AJAX views often return JSON instead of html, in which case you might use `render_to_string` instead. If you're still stuck please ask a new question, because it's not really related to the original problem.

Comment: Thank you! Of course I've done it with js... Actually, I use `render()` to display view, when I want to refresh a part of the DOM with js, I use `render_to_response()` to get the response from Django in a seperated view, I didn't know that `render()` can do it as well until I see the limits of `render_to_response()`. Once again million thanks